# display: table property in older browsers

Tags: html, css, firefox, vertical-alignment

In order to vertically align dynamic text I use `span` tag with `display: table-cell` property. It's wrapped by `div` with `display: table` property, and it works like it should.

But problem is that doesn't work in older firefox versions. Unfortunately, I need support for firefox 7 and greater.

Is there simplier solution beside using of real html tables?

Comment: Describe "vertically align"?

Comment: @Liam check [the MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/vertical-align).

Comment: @Barney I was thinking more down James's approach below. There's probably a better way to do what ever he's attempting to do, but I don't know because I don't know what he's trying to do.....If It's not a table it shouldn't be using table layout!

Comment: @Liam James' approach makes all sorts of assumptions and requirements (relies on specified height, can't expand to fit variable content, etc) that table layout doesn't need to deal with. You may believe `display: table` shouldn't be used — but it exists, has unique properties unaccounted for by the other technique, is what the OP's asking for, and it has documented support.

Comment: Combination of display:table & display:table-cell allows convenient solution when some text need to be verticaly centered in the middle of box. Text has dynamic length and sometimes for example it's fitted in one row and sometimes in three rows, but always is in the center/middle of box verticaly. I only don't know why it doesn't work in firefox versions lower than 10...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the MDN reference for the `display` property, `table` display via CSS [has been supported since Firefox version 1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/display#compat-desktop). You should be fine!

Comment: According to that your bigger problem is IE!

Comment: @Liam true, but the OP's question is about Firefox.

Comment: I didn't answer.. You're right. Problem is that Firefox versions 9 and older don't apply this property except to direct/first children..

Answer (score 1):

`display:table-cell` isn't the be all and end all of vertical alignment. Vertical alignment can still be easily achieved with CSS alone.

You'll need three things:

1. A containing divider with a specific height (fluid or static, it doesn't matter).
2. A relatively positioned "padding" divider with 50% height.
3. A container for the content you're wanting to vertically align.

You will need to know the exact height of your content container, however.

```
div#container {
    height:500px;
}

div#paddingDivider {
    height:50%;
}

div#contentContainer {
    margin:0 auto; /* Centrally align the element */
    height:100px; /* Declare the exact height of the element */
    margin-top:-50px; /* Position half of the element inside the padding divider */
}
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jpWWv/).

Comment: This works fine when text is always the same height, but when you have longer text that is splited in few rows it isn't verticaly centered in the middle of parent container.

Comment: That's why I mentioned that you need to know the exact height of the container. If the text isn't going to change, specify a `line-height`. Your total height is then `line-height * number of lines`. If the text is likely to change you'll need to use JavaScript to calculate the content container's `outer height` and set its `margin-top` attribute to half of that value.